# Is collection of polynomials with rational coefficients a field? - Exercise 4.C, Real Analysis, Bartle

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I would like to ask if my conclusion to the below problem is correct.

> Does the collection of polynomials with rational coefficients form a field?

**Solution.**

Let $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ be two polynomials of degree $m>n$.

$p(x)=a_{m}x^{m}+a_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\ldots+a_{0}$

$q(x)=b_{n}x^{n}+b_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+b_{0}$

Define addition $+$ as:

$\displaystyle{p(x)+q(x)=\sum_{1\le{i}\le{n}}(a_{i}+b_{i})x^{i}+\sum_{n<{i}\le{m}}a_{i}x^{i}}$

$+$ clearly satisfies axioms (A1)-(A3). The additive identity $\theta=0$. The additive inverse $\overline{p(x)}=-p(x)$.

Define multiplication $\times$ as:

$\displaystyle{p(x)\times{q(x)}=\sum_{j+k=0}^{m+n}\space\left(\sum_{j\le{m},k\le{n}}a_{j}b_{k}\right)x^{j+k}}$

$\times$ clearly satisfies axioms (M1)-(M3). The multiplicative identity is $e=1$. But, there is no multiplicative inverse.

Hence, the collection of polynomials with rational coefficients doesn't form a field.

Comment: Dear @Quasar: For showing that $\mathbb Q[x]$ is not a field you have to give a particular element whose inverse does not exist in $\mathbb Q[x]$.For instance can you see that $x$ does not have a inverse in $\mathbb Q[x]$ ?Infact the same idea shows that any $F[x]$ where $F$ is a field is not a field.It is good to note that $\mathbb Q[x]$ is a integral domain but not a field.

Comment: In fact no "non-constant" element of $\mathbb Q[x]$ is invertible.

Comment: @VictorBarg, got that! I thought of the counterexamples, but didn't state it. I have to be more careful and systematic in writing proofs. :)

Comment: Easy way: what happens to the degree of a polynomial when you multiply it by another polynomial?

Comment: @Oiler, yes, the degree of the polynomial add up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the analysis is correct. But there are not enough details about why there is no multiplicative inverse, and what element are you using to verify that (Since what you want to prove is that there exists an element which does not have inverse). For example, you could easily prove that $x$ does not have an inverse, even if the constant polynomial $5$ has the inverse $1/5$.

To give an insight of why there is no multiplicative inverse when the polynomial is not constant, think that $\deg (1)=0$ and $\deg (fg)\geq \deg(f)$ if the degrees are nonzero. If you suppose $\deg f\geq 1$, then for all $g$, $\deg (fg)\geq 1$ and $fg$ can't be 1.

To prove that $x$ does not have inverse, if you suppose

$$x(a_0+a_1x+\cdots)=0+a_0x +a_1+\cdots=1$$

You get $1=0$, a contradiction.